# How to draw a line using Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to draw a line using `Canvas` in Android. I tired this task in the `ontouchevent` using `touchesmove`, `touchesup` and `touchesdown`. The line appears when I touch end the mouse button. I want to draw a line like freehand drawing.

Here is my code,

```
switch (event.getAction()) 
{
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
mPath.reset();
mPath.moveTo(x, y);
mX = x;
mY = y;
invalidate();
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
    {
//mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
mX = x;
mY = y;
}
invalidate();
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);
mPath.reset();
invalidate();
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the `drawPath()` method is executed upon `ACTION_UP`. You'd need to call this method in `ACTION_MOVE` as well so your Path gets drawn on every move you make. For this to work you'd have to copy `mPath.lineTo(mX, mY)` to `ACTION_MOVE` as well of course.